# Flying from Canada with art supplies

Tags: air-travel, airports, airport-security, artworks

I always fly with just a carry-on and this time I'm thinking of taking some art supplies with me on my trip and I'm just wondering what the rules are.
I'll be taking pastels, china ink and nibs, a few graphite pencils for sketching and my notebooks. No oil/watercolor, no sharp and pointy tools, nothing too big either.

Also, I will most likely be flying from Canada and avoiding US airports.

Is there going to be a problem taking these through airport security?

**Update:** I've spoken to a couple of artist friends and their experience goes in the direction of the chosen answer, that is, no fluids over 100mL (that includes oily mediums), and the rest should be fine

**Update 2:** Here's a sample of what I'll be taking with me. Ink bottle is a 60mL container[image: supplies]

Comment: Note that the 100ml limit is per article, and all the 100ml items must be able to fit into a closed resealable <= 1L bag. http://www.aircanada.com/en/news/trav_adv/090101.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the photo in your question, I do not think there will be any problem, all the items shown are not listed under the prohibited carry-on items unless the ink will be in containers more than 100 ml or whatever quantity allowed by the airport authorities for liquids.

For more information about items and whether they are allowed on board or only in checked-in luggage you can [check this IATA document (PDF file)](http://www.iata.org/whatwedo/cargo/dgr/Documents/passenger-23A-DGR55-EN.PDF).

Comment: Any actual reference to support your opinion would be helpful.

Comment: @Karlson updated.

Comment: He might get in trouble for the amount of stuff if it is suspected of being for commercial use (smuggling).

Comment: @jwenting I don't think so, most likely the stuff won't be brand new :)

Comment: @MeNoTalk the stuff isn't new. I'll check for liquid restrictions, I'm also wondering if pencils and nibs can look suspicious because they're sharp and pointy.

Comment: @Blackbird57 never heard of a restriction on pencils, I guess nibs are fine too. They can't be more dangerous than bottles which are allowed onboard.

Comment: @MeNoTalk it seems like the kind of arbitrary thing that would be at the discretion of the official, but maybe I'm just being apprehensive

Comment: @Blackbird57 indeed, the security officers can deny any pointy stuff, but I doubt they would do that to pencils and nibs.

Comment: @Blackbird57 I think updating the question of a photo of the kit will help :)

Comment: @MeNoTalk good idea, I will when I'm back home

Comment: @Blackbird57 After seeing the photo, I think they will be allowed, I am sure like 99.9% :)

Comment: @MeNoTalk yes it did seem a little sillier to me as I was setting them up. Thanks :)